# Filter orders by product post type in WooCommerce admin orders list page

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I am new to WooCommerce, And I want to customize admin order list page. So basically I created new product type. Now I also made restriction that customer can purchase my custom product type's product or simple product type's product at a time.

Now in admin order listing page, I want to show order which has simple product type's product. How I can do this?

I searched a lot, I found an plugin which has filter to show order by product not product type. While studying that plugin I got to know that may be I can do this using `posts_where` action. But I don't have proper idea.

Comment: What do you mean "admin order list page"? Which "admin" page?

Comment: I mean page, that show all orders in back end

Comment: "Orders" in what? I don't get it.

Comment: I mean i want filter that show order in which, all product have same product type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following functions will add an additional filter dropdown to admin order list, allowing you to filter orders based on order items product post type:

```
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'admin_shop_order_by_product_type_filter' );
function admin_shop_order_by_product_type_filter(){
    global $pagenow, $post_type;

    if( 'shop_order' === $post_type && 'edit.php' === $pagenow ) {
        $domain     = 'woocommerce';
        $filter_id  = 'filter_product_type';
        $current    = isset($_GET[$filter_id])? $_GET[$filter_id] : '';
        $query_args = ['taxonomy' => 'product_type', 'fields' => 'names', 'orderby' => 'order'];

        echo '<select name="'.$filter_id.'">
        <option value="">' . __('Filter by Product post type', $domain) . '</option>';

        foreach ( get_terms($query_args) as $term_name ) {
            printf( '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $term_name,
                $term_name === $current ? '" selected="selected"' : '', ucfirst($term_name) );
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'process_admin_shop_order_product_type_filter' );
function process_admin_shop_order_product_type_filter( $query ) {
    global $pagenow, $post_type, $wpdb;

    $filter_id = 'filter_product_type';

    if ( $query->is_admin && 'edit.php' === $pagenow && 'shop_order' === $post_type
         && isset( $_GET[$filter_id] ) && $_GET[$filter_id] != '' ) {

        $order_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "
            SELECT DISTINCT o.ID
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts o
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items oi
                ON oi.order_id = o.ID
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim
                ON oi.order_item_id = oim.order_item_id
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships tr
                ON oim.meta_value = tr.object_id
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tt
                ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms t
                ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
            WHERE o.post_type = '$post_type'
            AND oim.meta_key = '_product_id'
            AND tt.taxonomy = 'product_type'
            AND t.name = '{$_GET[$filter_id]}'
        ");

        $query->set( 'post__in', $order_ids ); // Set the new "meta query"

        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 25 ); // Set "posts per page"

        $query->set( 'paged', ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ) ); // Set "paged"
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: This code works perfectly for filtering orders! But the order counts for each order is wrong. Any thoughts on that?