# How to create a filter dropdown on WooCommerce admin orders list?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, state, orders

I am trying to create a **shipping state** filter dropdown on WooCommerce admin orders list

First I have added a custom column for shipping state to admin orders list:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shipping_state_column', 100 );
function custom_shipping_state_column( $columns ){
$ordered_columns = array();

foreach( $columns as $key => $column ){
    $ordered_columns[$key] = $column;
    if( 'order_notes' == $key ){
        $ordered_columns['order_state'] = __( 'State/Province', 'woocommerce');
    }
}

return $ordered_columns;
}

 add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'shipping_state_order_list_column', 10, 1 );
 function shipping_state_order_list_column( $column )
 {
  global $post;

   if ( 'order_state' === $column ) {

      $order    = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
      echo $order->get_shipping_state();
    }

 }
```

And here's my dropdown filter, for shipping state:

```
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'filter_province');
    function filter_province(){
        global $typenow;
        global $wpdb;
        $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations';
        $sql = 'SELECT location_code FROM `'. $table . '`'; 
        $location_state = array();
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
        $location_name = array(
            'ABR'=>'ABR:Abra',
            'AGN'=>'AGN:Agusan del Norte',
            'AGS'=>'AGS:Agusan del Sur',
            'AKL'=>'AKL:Aklan',
            'ALB'=>'ALB:Albay',
            'ANT'=>'ANT:Antique',
            'APA'=>'APA:Apayao',
            'AUR'=>'AUR:Aurora',
            'BAS'=>'BAS:Basilan',
            'BAN'=>'BAN:Bataan',
            'BTN'=>'BTN:Batanes',
            'BTG'=>'BTG:Batangas',
            'BEN'=>'BEN:Benguet',
            'BIL'=>'BIL:Bilaran',
            'BOH'=>'BOH:Bohol',
            'BUK'=>'BUK:Bukidnon',
            'BUL'=>'BUL:Bulacan',
            'CAG'=>'CAG:Cagayan',
            'CAN'=>'CAN:Camarines Norte',
            'CAS'=>'CAS:Camarines Sur',
            'CAM'=>'CAM:Camiguin',
            'CAP'=>'CAP:Capiz',
            'CAT'=>'CAT:Catanduanez',
            'CAV'=>'CAV:Cavite',
            'CEB'=>'CEB:Cebu',
            'COM'=>'COM:Compostela Valley',
            'NCO'=>'NCO:Cotobato',
            'DAV'=>'DAV:Davao del Norte',
            'DAS'=>'DAS:Davao del Sur',
            'DAC'=>'DAC:Davao Occidental',
            'DAO'=>'DAO:Davao Oriental',
            'DIN'=>'DIN:Dinangat Island',
            'EAS'=>'EAS:Eastern Samar',
            'GUI'=>'GUI:Guimaras',
            'IFU'=>'IFU:Ifugao',
            'ILN'=>'ILN:Ilocos Norte',
            'ILS'=>'ILS:Ilocos Sur',
            'ILI'=>'ILI:Iloilo',
            'ISA'=>'ISA:Isabela',
            'KAL'=>'KAL:Kalinga',
            'LUN'=>'LUN:La Union',
            'LAG'=>'LAG:Laguna',
            'LAN'=>'LAN:Lanao del Norte',
            'LAS'=>'LAS:Lanao del Sur',
            'LEY'=>'LEY:Leyte',
            'MAG'=>'MAG:Maguindanao',
            'MAD'=>'MAD:Marinduque',
            'MAS'=>'MAS:Masbate',
            'MSC'=>'MSC:Misamis Occidental',
            'MSR'=>'MSR:Misamis Oriental',
            'MOU'=>'MOU:Mountain Province',
            'NEC'=>'NEC:Negros Occidental',
            'NER'=>'NER:Negros Oriental',
            'NSA'=>'NSA:Nothern Samar',
            'NUE'=>'NUE:Nueva Ecija',
            'NUV'=>'NUV:Nueva Vizcaya',
            'MDC'=>'MDC:Occidental Mindoro',
            'MDR'=>'MDR:Oriental Mindoro',
            'PLW'=>'PLW:Palawan',
            'PAM'=>'PAM:Pampanga',
            'PAN'=>'PAN:Pangasinan',
            'QUE'=>'QUE:Quezon',
            'QUI'=>'QUI:Quirino',
            'RIZ'=>'RIZ:Rizal',
            'ROM'=>'ROM:Romblon',
            'WSA'=>'WSA:Samar',
            'SAR'=>'SAR:Sarangani',
            'SIQ'=>'SIQ:Siquijor',
            'SOR'=>'SOR:Sorsogon',
            'SCO'=>'SCO:South Cotobato',
            'SLE'=>'SLE:Southern Leyte',
            'SUK'=>'SUK:Sultan Kudarat',
            'SLU'=>'SLU:Sulu',
            'SUN'=>'SUN:Surigao del Norte',
            'SUR'=>'SUR:Surigao del Sur',
            'TAR'=>'TAR:Tarlac',
            'TAW'=>'TAW:Tawi-Tawi',
            'ZWB'=>'ZWB:Zambales',
            'ZAN'=>'ZAN:Zamboanga del Norte',
            'ZAS'=>'ZAS:Zamboanga del Sur',
            'ZSI'=>'ZSI:Zamboanga Sibugay',
            '00'=>'00:Metro Manila'
        );
        $getCount = count($location_name);
        $location = array_values($location_name);

        // if post type is shop_order
        if ($typenow=='shop_order') {
            //check if our select has been sent and if so, is it set to "Currently Due"
            if (isset($_GET["get_province"])){
                $get_province = $_GET["get_province"];
                $selected = $get_province;
            } else {
                $selected = "";
            }
            echo "<select id='get_province' name='get_province'>";
            echo "<option value='' ".selected("", $selected )." >".__( 'State/Province', 'woocommerce' )."</option>";
            foreach($result as $res) {
                $data = explode(':',$res->location_code);
                for($i=0;$i<$getCount;$i++){
                    $location_state = explode(':',$location[$i]);
                    if($location_state[0] == $data[1]){
                        echo    "<option value= ".$data[1]." ".selected($data[1], $selected ).">".$location_state[1]."</option>";
                    }
                }

            }
            echo "</select>";

        }

    }
```

And here's my question: How to process the selected filter on admin orders list when I click the filter button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter orders by specific meta fields in WooCommerce admin orders list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62209407/filter-orders-by-specific-meta-fields-in-woocommerce-admin-orders-list)

Comment: Hello i used that code but it doesn't work idunno why but can you explain me on how to process once i've selected the state and submit to filter button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some mistakes, complications and missing things in your code.

The following will display a functional dropdown filter based on the shipping state location on admin order list (based on shipping settings allowed countries/states):

```
// Utility function to get all available shipping zones locations
function get_wc_shipping_zones_locations( ){
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_col("
        SELECT DISTINCT location_code 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations
    ");
}

// Add a dropdown to filter orders by state
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'add_shop_order_filter_by_state');
function add_shop_order_filter_by_state(){
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    if( 'shop_order' === $typenow && 'edit.php' === $pagenow ) {
        // Get available countries codes with their states code/name pairs
        $country_states = WC()->countries->get_allowed_country_states();

        // Initializing
        $filter_id   = 'shipping_state';
        $current     = isset($_GET[$filter_id])? $_GET[$filter_id] : '';

        echo '<select name="'.$filter_id.'">
        <option value="">'.__( 'Filter by State/Province', 'woocommerce' )."</option>";

        // Loop through shipping zones locations array
        foreach( get_wc_shipping_zones_locations() as $country_state ) {
            $country_state = explode(':', $country_state);
            $country_code  = reset($country_state);
            $state_code    = end($country_state);

            if ( isset( $country_states[$country_code][$state_code] ) 
            && $state_name = $country_states[$country_code][$state_code] ) {
                printf( '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $state_code, 
                    $state_code === $current ? '" selected="selected"' : '', 
                $state_name );
            }
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }
}

// Process the filter dropdown for orders by shipping state
add_filter( 'request', 'process_admin_shop_order_filtering_by_state', 99 );
function process_admin_shop_order_filtering_by_state( $vars ) {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    $filter_id = 'shipping_state';

    if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && 'shop_order' === $typenow 
    && isset( $_GET[$filter_id] ) && ! empty($_GET[$filter_id]) ) {
        $vars['meta_key']   = '_shipping_state';
        $vars['meta_value'] = $_GET[$filter_id];
        $vars['orderby']    = 'meta_value';
    }
    return $vars;
}
```

Then I have made some little changes to your shipping state custom column in admin orders list:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shipping_state_column', 100 );
function custom_shipping_state_column( $columns ){
    $sorted_columns = array();

    foreach( $columns as $key => $column ){
        $sorted_columns[$key] = $column;
        if( 'order_notes' == $key ){
            $sorted_columns['order_state'] = __( 'State/Province', 'woocommerce');
        }
    }
    return $sorted_columns;
}

 add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'shipping_state_order_list_column', 10, 1 );
 function shipping_state_order_list_column( $column ) {
     global $post, $the_order;

     if ( 'order_state' === $column && $shipping_state = $the_order->get_shipping_state() ) {
          echo $shipping_state;
     }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Related answer: [Filter orders by product post type in WooCommerce admin orders list page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56132215/filter-orders-by-product-post-type-in-woocommerce-admin-orders-list-page/56135048#56135048)

Comment: Hello thank you so much it works perfectly now read your code and precisely

Comment: @AlexanderDeMesa I have just updated my code, there was something custom that I use for debug, that I have removed: `print_pr($country_state);`… So remove it too as this will throw an error.

Comment: Hello @LoicTheAztec thanks for the info and sorry this is my first time to post on stackoverflow. Ok i will follow your suggestion :)